# Storing a multidimensional array from another array and calling it in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, session

So i have a shopping cart creation issue, most of the code is working, just the final part of the For each loop is not be called. I believe the problem is somehow the array that it uses is being overwritten.

**A quick overview of what is happening.**

A shop item is created by a foreachloop(to avoid confusion i will call it FOR1) that has multiple options, the creation of the array that holds the information about each FOR1  item is only created on a submit button, as this is the time an item gets added to a cart.

The data needs to be stored in a session. (*The start session function is already called at the top of the page)

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_1"])){
    $color = $_POST['color_select'];
    $size = $_POST['size_select'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $range = $_POST['range'];
    $item_array = array(0 => array('i_color' => $color, 'i_size' => $size, 'i_price' => $price, 'i_range' => $range));
    $_SESSION["item"] = $item_array;
}
```

The shopping cart then detects that an item has been added to the session array and displays it accordingly. It then calls through however many items there are in the $_SESSION["item"] array in another foreach loop (FOR2).

```
if(empty($_SESSION["item"])){
        echo "the cart is empty";
    }
    else{
        foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key){ 
        echo $key["i_range"]; // this is actually inside a styled div
        echo $key["i_color"]; // this is actually inside a styled div
    }
}
```

The code works to display the item that was selected by the submit_1 button and remains persistent throughout the session(*ie leaving and coming back to the page the $SESSION["item"] stays in the array). However it only displays 1 item. When the button is clicked again, or clicked for another shop item, it only displays that item and doesn't add a new item to the FOR2 function.

I am assuming that the issue is that the array gets overwritten each time the button is clicked. Or i have misunderstood the submit button functionality, as all the items use the submit_1 tag. In which case how would i dynamically create a new submit button each time it is pressed?

** I also have a remove item function that unsets $item_array that successfully removes the array item so that the shopping cart is empty again.

**Update**
Following the answer below, the additional step you need to add is nest the foreach loop inside another foreach loop. Like so.

```
foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key){ 
    foreach($key as $list){
    echo $list["i_color"]; 
    echo $list["i_range"]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_1"])){
  $color = $_POST['color_select'];
  $size = $_POST['size_select'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $range = $_POST['range'];
  $item_array = array('i_color' => $color, 'i_size' => $size, 'i_price' => $price, 'i_range' => $range);
  $_SESSION["item"][] = $item_array;
}
```

Comment: So that works somewhat. It adds new items and stores them, but the info isn't displayed. Do i need to add the extra brakets anywhere eles? ive tried on the 
if(empty($_SESSION["item"][])){echo "the cart is empty";}''

Comment: @Paddy no. this looks ok: if(empty($_SESSION["item"])){echo "the cart is empty";}

Comment: Anything on the foreach loop? the brackets i'm assuming are a reference to the multidimensional array. So the array is calling, just the elements are not being called properly and showing blank. 
foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key){ 
echo "range is" . $key["i_range"]; }//The key is blank

Comment: @Paddy I need to see how the array looks like. Would you put a print_r($_SESSION['item']) in your question?

Comment: So outside the foreach loop is pulls the array Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [i_color] => Shiney Gold [i_size] => + 1.50 [i_price] => 79.95 [i_range] => Cavu 1 ) ) ) 

and the same thing inside the foreachh loop. So somewhere $key is not linking to session["item"]

Comment: @Paddy are you sure you add items like this: `$item_array = array('i_color' => $color, 'i_size' => $size, 'i_price' => $price, 'i_range' => $range);
  $_SESSION["item"][] = $item_array;`

Comment: Hey Marvin, I got it! so turn out as its a multi-dimensional array i needed to call 2 foreachloops. Will update the code accordingly. Thank you so much for your help.